# Select all in ecto query

Tags: sql, elixir, phoenix-framework, ecto

Here is a raw SQL:

```sql
SELECT p.*, u.name
FROM posts p
JOIN users u
ON p.user_id = u.id
```

How do I translate it into Ecto query?

```
query = from p in Post,
  join: u in User,
  on: p.user_id == u.id,
  select: {[p], u.name}
```

Is the code above correct?

Comment: Have you tried it?

Comment: @Dai Yeah! I've tried it but it returned [BadMapError]. I'm not sure the "select: {[p], u.name}" syntax is correct though.

Answer (score 0):

Here is an extensive documentation for [`select/3`](https://hexdocs.pm/ecto/Ecto.Query.html#select/3) syntax.

```elixir
select: %{p | username: u.name}
```

Answer (score 0):

Alternatively `select_merge/3` can be used:

```
query = from p in Post,
  join: u in User,
  on: p.user_id == u.id,
  select: p,
  select_merge: ^%{name: u.name}
```